# Cpp file handling using transaction like sql, commit and rollback

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, desktop

I need to write in multiple files if anything wrong happens then rollback all changes and also commit same time in all files in cpp windows. is it possible or if there any library please suggest.

Comment: Not possible in Standard C++ without OS support or external libraries (that wrap the OS calls).  Please read [ask] regarding asking for libraries or other external resources.

Comment: Not possible in most operating systems, either. It's just not a thing that exists.

Comment: @Aconcagua works until a 2nd "something goes wrong" happens during the recovery for the first "something went wrong" etc.

Comment: Is this a single application (client) needing to do this, or could there be multiple instances (clients), all vying for the same set of files (server)?

Comment: Do you mean File System Transactions (Windows actually does have such at thing, but poorly implemented) or source files version control? Consider using a CVS system for the latter - although you can achieve (almost) the same if you close VS, copy the solution folder somewhere else and reopen it (easier if you are working alone).

Comment: [Transactional NTFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/about-transactional-ntfs) seems like a potential candidate, though I don't know about its current support status. That said, if you require referential integrity, use a database. SQLite ships with Windows, for example.

Comment: @franji1 it is for multiple clients accessing same data set.

Answer (score 0):

This would require kind of mechanism for file system operations resembling those database transactions you mention, which the C++ standard doesn't provide, so you'd entirely rely on the operating system – which none of the ones I'm aware of provides either (maybe there's some specialised linux distribution that does so?).

All you can do is trying to get as close as possible, e.g. by the following approach:

1. Write out all these files all as temporary copies, at best into a dedicated temporary directory.
2. *Rename* all original files/move them into the dedicated directory (we'll keep them as backup for now).
3. Rename/move all new temporaries to original file names/folders.
4. Finally delete the backups.

If anything goes wrong then you can delete all the new temporaries again and rename the backups back to their original names – unless the error occurred on deleting the backups, then you might just leave the remaining ones.

If you retain a log file and add an entry for every task when it is started as well as when completed you exactly know when an error occurred and can safely restore the original state later on even if *recovery* failed, as the actual point of failure can be determined exactly that way (similarly to the logging database management systems do internally as well to realise their transactions).